# Underfitting and Overfitting at the same time?

Tags: logistic, interpretation, overfitting, under-sampling

I am using a Logistic Regression Classifier on the [Airline Cancellation dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yuanyuwendymu/airline-delay-and-cancellation-data-2009-2018/).
Please note that the training set was undersampled (in order to balance classes) while the test set was left as it was.
Can you help me interpreting these results?

```
log loss   F1 score    Accuracy   Recall    Specificity Precision     AUPRC     AUROC   run_type
0.654       0.622       0.622      0.624      0.621      0.621       0.656      0.666   Train
0.647       0.050       0.619      0.623      0.619      0.026       0.031      0.665   Test
```

Specifically, the training and test losses are both high, so I would say that I'm using a too simple model -> underfitting.
However, the metrics: F1 and AUPRC (that are the one I'm considering because of the imabalance setting) are higher in training set than test set -> overfitting?

Comment: What was the class balance before (and after) undersampling?

Comment: @BenReiniger Before undersampling the training set had an imbalance ratio ( #regular/#cancelled) of 61.88, after undersampling 1.0. With this setting I still get a training set of 1.5 million datapoints (an half is about cancelled flight and the other is about regular ones).

Comment: Hrm, this is surprising to me.  I would expect the test set's loss to be much worse, since the model has reason to expect much higher probabilities of cancellation than the truth.  The same normally explains a hit to precision, but I would expect an improved recall (assuming you're using a fixed threshold for both sets).  And I thought that both AUROC and AUPRC should be unaffected, caring only about rank-ordering.  Maybe you can share your code?